# How to send data post data to jobs api elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to post data to a machine learning api using elasticsearch. What format does the json docs need to be in?

I've attempted to send data with json docs separated by newline in a txt file. I've also tried converting back and forth to json using dump and load to no avail. The documentation states that the documents can be separated by whitespace, but no matter what I try it won't accept them.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ml-post-data.html

Here is an example of a json doc saved as file_name.json:

```py
[{"myid": "id1", "client": "client1", "submit_date": 1514764857},
 {"my_id": "id2", "client": "client_2", "submit_date": 1514764857}]
```

Here is the basic code needed to post data:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.client.xpack import MlClient

es = elastic_connection()
es_ml = MlClient(es)

def post_training_data(directory='Training Data', file_name='file_name.json'):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file_name), mode='r') as train_file:
            train_data = json.load(train_file)
            es_ml.post_data(job_id=job_id, body=train_data)

post_training_data()
```

This is the specific error I am getting with this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "..\train_model.py", line 218, in post_training_data
    self.es_ml.post_data(job_id=self.job_id, body=train_data)
  File "..\inc_anamoly\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "..\inc_anamoly\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\xpack\ml.py", line 81, in post_data
    body=self._bulk_body(body))
AttributeError: 'MlClient' object has no attribute '_bulk_body'
```

Comment: post the full tb please

Comment: I added the rest of the traceback removing file paths.

Comment: I don't think you're calling `MlClient` correctly because its not inheriting the `_bulk_body` method from the `Elasticsearch` parent class properly

Comment: Then it's specific to the post_data method because I've been able to create, open, close, and delete jobs via the MlClient instance I've created. https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/xpack.html#machine-learning-apis

Comment: yes but if you go to the source code you'll see that only `post_data` and `find_file_structure` are the only two methods which rely on this inherited function

Comment: That looks to be on the right track because if I remove body=self._bulk_body(body) from the post_data method in ml.py and replace with body=body I was able to send one json doc {"myid": "id1", "client": "client1", "submit_date": 1514764857}. It's not immediately clear how to incorporate the body in the current structure, but I will post back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug. Issue reported.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/959